# Delete Data from Non-Nullable Column in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, nullable, non-nullable

Question: I have table with three column, with column names APP_NAME, APP_TYPE and VALUE_TIME.

[image]

I would like to edit VALUE_TIME for particular APP_NAME and APP_TYPE. So my query should look like below mentioned if VALUE_TIME column is Nullable. So what would be the best way to delete the data for particular condition ?

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME
SET VALUE_TIME = null
WHERE APP_NAME = 'XYZ'
AND APP_TYPE = 'TEST';
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you have two choices.  A) Make VALUE_TIME nullable.  B) Set the value to a valid string, such as `''`

Comment: @Mike Christensen : `''` is not valid string non-null in Oracle (empty string converted to `NULL` internally)

Comment: @a1ex07 - Ah, yea I forgot the Oracle casts `''` to NULL (in violation of the SQL standard).  Right you are..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Answer, You can't update non-nullable column data to NULL or '   ' in oracle. I could only think of is Alter the column to have null.

```
ALTER 
TABLE TABLE_NAME 
MODIFY VALUE_TYPE VARCHAR2(500) NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to delete the row:

```
DELETE TABLE_NAME WHERE APP_NAME = 'XYZ' AND APP_TYPE = 'TEST';
```

The column VALUE_TYPE is defined as NOT NULL, so you can't set it to null. You could alter the table to make it nullable:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME MODIFY VALUE_TYPE VARCHAR2(500) NULL;
```

And then run the UPDATE statement in your question.

Hopefully this answers your question - it wasn't clear what you want to do exactly.